# Why would a FaceBook application "work" on a profile, but not a page?

Tags: facebook

I made a FaceBook application that works fine on profiles, but I can't figure out how to get it to show on a FaceBook page.

For example, after I visit the application canvas URL, allow the application, then edit application settings and "add" to box and tab view...  I cannot click the "plus" symbol to the right of the tabs in order to add a tab for the application. It does not appear in the list of available applications.

Meanwhile, the application is working/showing up on profiles with no issues.

I DID check the "Installable to Pages" checkbox on the application (authentication tab) settings.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... figured it out.

To add an application to a FaceBook page:

1. Go to the Application Profile Page
2. Click the "Add to Page" link
3. Go to the Page where you would like to add the application
4. Click the "plus" symbol to the right of the tabs and select your application.